# Combine - mapping errors to different types

Tags: swift, combine

I've created this publisher chain:

```
enum ViewState {
  case loading, loaded([Person]), error(String)
}

var viewStatePublisher: AnyPublisher<ViewState, Never> {
  service.fetchPeople()
    .map { ViewState.loaded($0) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

`fetchPeople` can fail, and I'd like to propagate that down the publisher chain as a `ViewState.error(String)` value. Here's a rough idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
service.fetchPeople()
  .mapError { error -> AnyPublisher<ViewState, Never> in
    ViewState.error(error.localizedDescription)
  }
  .map { ViewState.loaded($0) }
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

However, `mapError` doesn't work that way. I'm having trouble finding other alternatives to doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `catch` to replace errors thrown by the upstream publisher with a new downstream Publisher.

Inside the `catch`, you can wrap the error in a `Just`, which is a `Publisher` that emits a single value immediately.

```
service.fetchPeople()
    .map { ViewState.loaded($0) }
    .catch { Just(ViewState.error($0.localizedDescription)) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to convert a stream that can error to a publisher that can `Never` fail is with `replaceError`. See my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsErrorHandlers/operatorsreplaceerror.html

```
service.fetchPeople()
    .map { ViewState.loaded($0) }
    .replaceError { with: ViewState.error("Darn") }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This outputs an `AnyPublisher<ViewState, Never>` which is just what you're after.